# Is there a way in Embarcadero Delphi 10.3 IDE debugger to monitor variable in other procedures after it is used in a procedural variable?

Tags: delphi

Is there a way in Embarcadero Delphi 10.3 IDE debugger to monitor variable (x) in other procedures (TestProcedure, DebugProcedure) after it is used in a procedural variable (ReasonProcedure)? Watch and Evaluate/Modify returns 'Innaccesible value' or 'E2003 Undeclared identifier'.

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}
uses
  System.SysUtils;

procedure ReasonProcedure(p: TProc);
begin
  p;
end;

procedure TestProcedure;
var
  x: integer;

  procedure DebugProcedure;
  begin
    x := 1;
  end;

begin
  x := 0;
  DebugProcedure;
  ReasonProcedure(procedure
  begin
    x := 2;
  end);
end;

begin
  TestProcedure;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is this:

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}
uses
  System.SysUtils;

var P2X: PINT;

procedure ReasonProcedure(p: TProc);
begin
  p;
end;

procedure TestProcedure;
var
  x: integer;

  procedure DebugProcedure;
  begin
    x := 1;
  end;

begin
  P2X:=@x;  // Keep address of local variable in P2X pointer //
  x := 0;
  DebugProcedure;
  ReasonProcedure(procedure
  begin
    x := 2;
  end);
end;

begin
  TestProcedure;
end.
```

and then put a watch on P2X^

I'm not 100% sure it'll work across anonymous methods, but I believe it will.

If you don't want to add a new variable to contain the pointer to the one you want to watch, you'll need to put a breakpoint on the entry to TestProcedure, issue an Evaluate on @x,x to get its address, and then issue a Watch on PINT($<addr>)^

Note, however, that in the latter case, you will have to refresh the watch on each subsequent entry of TestProcedure, as the variable is on the stack and may be on a different address next time around.